# widget used in jquery themeroller?

Tags: jquery

I need to customize my web site like theme roller ready and i don't know about the widgets which are used in jquery theme roller so i need the details about widget which is used in jquery themeroller ready, `i searched a lot but no use in that`. could any help me in that. thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1093-how-to-style-jquery-ui-widgets-with-themeroller/ help?

Comment: @RahulTripathi thanks but how can i create our own themeroller to our site?

Comment: still i didn't get any good answer please..

Comment: @JasCav i want to make my own themeroller on my site. is there any help?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [*lavoiesl*](https://github.com/lavoiesl/jQueryUIThemeRoller) has done a good job collecting all the necessary files needed to make a local version of Themeroller. IMHO I would not use this tool for it is not supported in all browsers, and, you will have to give all of your elements certain class names.

But, if you wish to go with this route, all you will need to do is upload the contents of [*lavoiesl*](https://github.com/lavoiesl/jQueryUIThemeRoller) repository and navigate to /themeroller/index.php and away you go. Hack away!

FYI: upon testing, I found that in the _head.php file the app_screen style sheet is no longer available at http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/app_css/app_screen.css, it is now located at: http://static.jquery.com/ui/themeroller/app_css/app_screen.css.

Here is the test page I put together from the steps listed above: http://jeffreykarbowski.com/themeroller/themeroller/

Good luck!